# When can one reboot from inside a chroot environment?

Tags: linux, chroot, reboot

Sometimes when I chroot into some folder , I could use `reboot` to reset my box, but sometimes I can't.

So I want to know why I could do that sometimes and why.

**UPDATE**

The chroot environment is another Linux system installed on a different partition and I prepare the chroot as follows:

```
mount --bind /dev chroot/dev
mount --bind /sys chroot/sys
mount -t proc proc chroot/proc
```

Comment: Are we really expected to know what your chroot environment looks like?

Comment: I second the request for more information. How exactly do you enter the chroot? What sequence of commands do you use?

Comment: updated , please check

Comment: So in which cases were you NOT able to reboot? What was different?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's `/dev/initctl`, which is (often? always?) used to interact with `init` (pid 1), e.g. [Upstart](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/initctl.8.html).

From your updated `chroot` entrance sequence, you bound `/dev/`, so there is a `/dev/initctl` in your `chroot`.  Triggering a reboot can this way reboot your system.

This probably won't be this way much longer, as many distributions (e.g. [Debian](http://wiki.debian.org/ReleaseGoals/RunDirectory)) introduce `/run/`, where `initctl` then resides.